# allocator_traits::construct() vs allocator_traits::allocate()

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

C++11 provides the `std::allocator_traits` class as the standard way to use allocators. The static function `std::allocator_traits::construct()` takes a *pointer* to where the object should be constructed. The `std::allocator_traits::allocate()` static function, however, returns an `allocator::pointer` value, which only has to behave like a pointer but it is not necessarily one (in general, although `std::allocator::pointer` is required to be a pointer).

How is one supposed to use the allocation and construction static methods if, in general, they will work with incompatible types? Can they be used only if the `pointer` type is actually convertible to a normal plain pointer?

Comment: +1  This is an exceptionally insightful question at this time.  There are very few C++ programmers exploring these waters.  Implementors have to.  Which leads me to ask the question:  Are you a std::lib implementor?

Comment: @HowardHinnant: Thanks! The question is connected to the design of a small vector class with a couple of extra bells and whistles over ``std::vector`` (e.g., automatic use of static storage up to a few elements, support for SSE and other vector instructions, etc.). Just wanted to try to do things the "proper" way with respect to allocator support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two techniques to do this depending on what you have at the moment.

If you have an lvalue expression, say the value field in a node, then you can use std::addressof like so:

```
allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(alloc, std::addressof(ptr->value), ...);
```

where `ptr` is an `allocator_type::pointer`.

However if you don't have a field to dereference and you want to convert an `allocator_type::pointer` to `T*`, there's a trick you need to implement first:

```
template <class T>
inline
T*
to_raw_pointer(T* p) noexcept
{
    return p;
}

template <class Pointer>
inline
typename std::pointer_traits<Pointer>::element_type*
to_raw_pointer(Pointer p) noexcept
{
    return p != nullptr ? ::to_raw_pointer(p.operator->())
                        : nullptr;
}
```

And now you can say:

```
allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(alloc, to_raw_pointer(ptr), ...);
```

Comment: Oh wow, one never finishes learning... The semantics of ``operator->()`` are pretty mind boggling :D

Comment: why do you write `::` in front of `to_raw_pointer(p.operator->())`? Is there a danger that ADL will cause interference otherwise, or is it just a habit? I would presume that when both overloads are in the same namespace it wouldn't matter.

Comment: I think it was paranoia that lookup would only find the second overload, but on testing I find it isn't needed after all.  I occasionally stumbled across issues like this when writing member swap, and so have gotten in the habit of just always qualifying unless I really want ADL to take over.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with C++20, there is [`std::to_address`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address), proposed in [P0653](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0653r2.html).